# Corrupt Save File Problem Csharp Opentk

Tags: c#, opengl, maps, opentk

I am trying to save player's objects but my loaded result is corrupt and placed in weird shapes like 3D arrows.
Weirdly enough when terrain is saved, the terrain is fine but objects added later cause the problem.
I am using OpenTK for OpenGL.

What I expect: [image: expected result]

What I get:
[image: Result That Happens]

The file seems to contain some repeated parts? Here is a part of the (large) file I end up with:

```
(0; 0; 0),(0; 0; 0),(0; 0; 1),(0; 1; 0),(1; 0; 0),(0; 0; 2),(0; 2; 0),(2; 0; 0),(0; 0; 0)
```

Here is my loading code:

```
void MapLoad(string filelocation)
{
    string[] map_;
    string line = File.ReadAllText(filelocation);//
    map_ = line.Split(new char[] { ',', ';', '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);





for (int xj = 0; xj < line.Split(',').Length; xj += 3)
        {
            // Here xj is an index of a X coordinate, xj + 1 is an index of a Y coordinate, xj + 2 is an index of a Z coordinate
//copied pasted for suring answer will work
         block_file.Add(new Vector3(Int32.Parse(map_[xj]), Int32.Parse(map_[xj + 1]), Int32.Parse(map_[xj + 2])));
        }

}
```

The `Vector3` is from OpenTK.

Here is my writing code:

```
if(key.KeyCode == Keys.F7)
{ 
    File.WriteAllText("usermap.txt", String.Join(",",block_file));//new char[] { ',', ';', '(', ')' 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indexing is broken.

```
for (int xj = 0; xj < line.Split(',').Length - 2; xj++)
```

Inside the loop you are accessing `xj`, `xj + 1` and `xj + 2`. Currently then your next iteration will use `xj + 1`, `xj + 2` and `xj + 3`. You didn't include how you write the save file, but I assume there is a similar issue there as you seem to write vector components into wrong places.

Instead, you want to increment the loop counter with 3 each time, so that instead of reading the same values 3 times, you only read them once and then move onto the next element. So `xj += 3` is what your loop increment should be.

```
for (int xj = 0; xj < map_.Length; xj += 3)
{
    // Here xj is an index of a X coordinate, xj + 1 is an index of a Y coordinate, xj + 2 is an index of a Z coordinate
}
```

Also note that you want to iterate until `map_.Length`, since this is what contains your coordinate values, not `line.Split(",").Length`.

Comment: how i can do that beacuse if i do thing you said it will read only small portion of file + Int32.Parse(map_[xj]) reads x coord of vector

Comment: No, with an increment of 3 it will read each vector written to the file exactly once. `xj` will refer to the X-component, `xj + 1` will refer to the Y-component, `xj + 2` will refer to the Z component. The next X-component is at index `xj + 3`, so your for loop should increment by 3.

Comment: done thing you said but half of map is not rendered but its rendered half correclty now. probably fixing this i need put garble data in file too right?

Comment: Could you add your updated code to the question body?

Comment: updated you can check it now

Comment: See my edit about changing the loop limit to `map_.Length`.

Comment: thanks so much :) going to credit you in game's credits screen